# Read certificate from pdf

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, x509certificate

I'm using ITextSharp in order to read certificate informations from digitally signed pdf document.

The `ITextSharp.Text.Pdf.PdfPKCS7` class exposes three properties:

- `Certificates` (as list)
- `SignCertificate` (as single object)
- `SignCertificateChain` (as list)

How can I combine these three properties in order to achieve all info about a single certificate?

I'd be able to show all certificate path (all nested certificates).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Certificates` gives you the list in no particular order, including certificates that weren't used for the main signature.

`SignCertificate` gives you the certificate of the actual signer.

`SignCertificateChain` gives you the list where the first Certificate is the SignCertificate, the next is the certificate of the instance that issued the SignCertificate, the next is the certificate of the instance that issued the previous certificate, and so on. This can return less certificates than `Certificates`, because only the certificates used for the main signature will be returned.

So you don't need to 'combine' the properties to show the certificate path, you just need SignCertificateChain. Note that your question isn't entirely clear:

> 'all info about a *single* certificate'

kind of contradicts with

> 'show *all* certificate path (all nested certificates)'

If you want to visualize the chain that resulted into the signing certificate, you need to look at more than a single certificate (unless the certificate was self-signed in which case there's only one element in the chain).

Comment: Ok yuor answer was just what I was looking for. So, through SigncertificateChain I can restore main certificate chain such as it way my purpose. Thank you very mauch.

Comment: uhmmm..just one thing: is exist any way to retrieve public key of certificates? I've peeked in pdfPkcs7 class but I've not found any way.

Comment: I only know how to do this in Java. It's a method in the Certificate or the X509Certificate class.

Comment: Sure..I'm able to in C# with X509Certificate2 class, but in this case I'm reading a kin of certificate through itextSharp class, that is Pdfpkcs7. (remember? the certificate I read is inside pdf doc).

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. In Java PdfPKCS7 exposes the Certificate objects that can be cast to X509Certicate objects. I've never understood C#. Surely you can't blame me for that.

Comment: Ok, but I haven't comprehend you. In your answer you explained me what it means with SignCertificateChain. Then, you talk about need to look at more than one single certificate in order to visualize the chain that resulted in. Maybe I haven't grabbed what it means..

Comment: Please read chapter 5 of http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures In that chapter, I use the elements in signCertificateChain for instance to check if no certificate in the chain has been revoked.