# iTextSharp - Read certificate from pdf

Tags: c#, itext, x509certificate

Following on the question by me on this post [read-certificate-from-pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12477580/read-certificate-from-pdf) I'm using SignCertificateChain in order to achieve all certificate chain about pdf signed.

However, I note that class returns only one item (my certificate), conversely, if I open the same document with adobe acrobat I can read 2 certificate (my cert and that about who released me).

Am I mssing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a sample PDF, it's very hard to help you. I'm currently writing the (Java-based) documentation on this subject, and I can't reproduce your problem: http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures See chapter 5 dealing with certificate verification.

Comment: Well, I've seen your pdf documentation (chapter 5), but I'haven't found any way to retrieve all certificates chain. You simply mentionated SignCertificateChain to achieve the entirely chain, but how I already claimed I just get one certificate. Note that I don't create any key store, instead I use PdfPkcs7 object only to read all "things" and I expect to find all cert chain in this object, without create any key store. Could you peek my pdf sample? Can I send you this file?

Comment: If you can't post the PDF here, we only accept two channels: either you register on our free mailing list and post the PDF there; or you register for premium support and you make a support ticket.

Comment: Ok, as soon as I'll can do it I'll post my signed test pdf. However, I'have just discovered that with another adobe reader (earlier version) it return me the same result of ITextSharp, namely a single certificate. What do you thin about..?

Comment: I think there's only one certificate, but I can't tell you with 100% certainty without seeing the PDF.

Comment: Yes. You was right, it's contains a single certificate only. I don't understand why an adobe reader return me 2 certificate, however now I'm sure that it's a just one. Thank you.